# How to create a DateTime field in bigquery and update it in golang?

Tags: go, google-bigquery

here is basically my creation script for bigquery in golang  :

```
type data_pix struct {
    Id string
    IdC string
    Stamp   int64
    Tag []string


}
func createTable(client *bigquery.Client, datasetID, tableID string) error {
    ctx := context.Background()
    // [START bigquery_create_table]
    schema, err := bigquery.InferSchema(data_pix{})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    table := client.Dataset(datasetID).Table(tableID)
    if err := table.Create(ctx, schema); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // [END bigquery_create_table]
    return nil
}
```

for the moment i use mainly a timestamp in Int64.

But i am looking for any example on how to add Datetime to my struct and btw add Datetime to my data

Thanks and regards

Comment: I know very little about Go, but does this help? You can see how `InferSchema` is implemented, which might get you started with defining a `DATETIME` column instead: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/blob/master/bigquery/schema.go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have not used the bigquery, however I had a look at the [godoc](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#hdr-Schemas) and [source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/blob/master/bigquery/schema.go#L202).

It seems, you have to use data type `civil.DateTime` [reference](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/blob/master/civil/civil.go#L196) in the struct.

**For e.g:**

As per godoc and source code, following should create [DateTime](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#datetime-type) field.

```
type data_pix struct {
   Id      string
   IdC     string
   Stamp   civil.DateTime
   Tag     []string
}

schema, err := bigquery.InferSchema(data_pix{})
// now schema should represent DateTime Field
```

There is a [function](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/blob/9aed268b14ec7c57a2aa86795c0e63e138084524/civil/civil.go#L204) to get `civil.DateTime` from `time.Time`. I would suggest you have a look at this [go sourcecode](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/blob/master/civil/civil.go) to know more.